# How to drop those columns that exist in the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following line of code that is used to drop some columns in a DataFrame. It may happen that some of these columns do not exist in the DataFrame.

```
df =

col1  col2  col3
asa   132   4534
dfd   24    4252


cols = ["col1", "colB"] 
df.drop(cols, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

How can I skip the columns that do not exist?

Expected output:

```
df =

col2  col3
132   4534
24    4252
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `errors='ignore'`

```
cols = ["col1", "colB"] 
df.drop(cols, axis=1, errors='ignore', inplace=True)
df
Out[167]: 
   col2  col3
0   132  4534
1    24  4252
```

Comment: How do you copy your output from jupyter notebook like that?

Comment: but do you just highlight it with your mouse and copy-paste? That doesn't work for me. @Wen-Ben

Comment: @crytting that is coding gui, I am using pycharm , not jupyter

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

col1 = ['asa', 'dfd']
col2 = [132, 24]
col3 = [4523, 4252]
cols = {'col1':col1,'col2':col2, 'col3':col3}

df = pd.DataFrame(cols)

drop_cols = ['col1', 'colB']

for col in drop_cols:
    if col in df.columns.values:
        df.drop(col, inplace = True, axis = 1)

df
```

returns what you're looking for.

```
    col2     col3
0   132      4523
1   24       4252
```